# Sending data to modal window, then posting form in original window

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using php and jquery. I have a form in php, after filling in the form, I wanna be able to click submit and send the data to a modal window pop up, where the form data is displayed. There will be an additional textbox to fill in, then after clicking another submit, this textbox + the form data will be submitted to a processing page on the parent window.

So basically, i dunno how to -

1) Pass form data from form to modal window - do i use json stringify and if so how?

2) How to submit from the modal window the previous form data + data in the textbox back to the original form

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2) How to submit from the modal window
>   the previous form data + data in the
>   textbox back to the original form

After opening new window with `window.open()`, you can access "parent window" via `window.opener`. E.g., if you have `<form id='foo'/>` in parent window, you can access it as `$(window.opener).find('#foo')` from "modal" window.

---

> 1) Pass form data from form to modal
>   window - do i use json stringify and
>   if so how?

What about sending POST to the same window, validating data, reloading the page and if everything is successful in the first form, then showing modal window after reloading the page? Data could be stored in `$_SESSION`, that way you don't have to worry about passing data between windows. Or, if you really want to pass data to the form of child window, you can do something like this (not tested):

```
var modalWindow = window.open(
    URL, 
    '_blank', 
    'width=400, height=300, left=100, top=300'
);
modalWindow.load(function(){
    var form = $(this).find('#idOfFormInModalWindow');
    form.find('[name=someField1]').val('someValue1');
    form.find('[name=someField2]').val('someValue2');
    form.find('[name=someField3]').val('someValue3');
});
```

`someValue1`, `someValue2`, `someValue3` would be values from `$_POST`, passed through [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode).

Comment: thanks for the answer - the reason why i wanted to send data to the window was to display, somewhat like a preview. user will then input some text, then click submit, then only now will i post the whole form and perform database insertion

Comment: So... In the main window, use `window.open()` to create a modal window. Store returned value into a variable. Create its `load` event handler in similar way as I already posted, with "someValue1" etc being values from the form in the main window (e.g., `$('#someField1').val()`). This is done in javascript of main window. After submitting form in modal window, check if everything's OK and either display some error message (if necessary), or use `window.close()` from the modal window to close it. From modal window, you can access main window for manipulations via `window.opener`.